# HTTP POST Request in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I am trying to post the id of a user to my service (addGrades) but i am currently confused on how to get that done. My first attempt was to capture the id from the URL using ActivateRoute but that wouldn't work out.

```
//service 

    addGrades(user:any){

            const body = JSON.stringify(user);
            const headers = new Headers();
            headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            return this.http.post('http://localhost:9000/routes/grades/v1/course/'+user.id+'/student', body, {headers: headers})
                .map((data:Response) => data.json());

        }




 //component.ts



export class Component implements OnInit{

private id;







constructor(private httpService: HttpService , private _route:ActivatedRoute) {}


ngOnInit() {
    this._route.params.subscribe(params => {if (params['id']) {
        this.id = params['id'];
    }
    })
}


    Submit(id){

            this.httpService.addGrades(this.model)
                .subscribe(data => {

                    console.log(data);
                })
        }
```

Comment: "that didn't work out" is a much too vague description. What are you doing? What do you expect to happen? What happens instead? Note that setting the content-type header and stringifying to json is unnecessary. Just post the object, and Angular will do that for you.

Comment: @JBNizet I am trying to bind the id captured from the URL into my service url this.http.post('http://localhost:9000/routes/grades/v1/course/'+user.id+'/student', body, {headers: headers}). The submit function should bind the id

Comment: The submit method doesn't do anything with the ID. If you want to store it in the model, then do it.

Comment: i have update the question. Sorry i don't really get your statement

Comment: Answer these 3 questions: What are you doing? What do you expect to happen? What happens instead?

Comment: i am capturing the user id from the url, then bind it to the url          this.http.post('http://localhost:9000/routes/grades/v1/course/'+user.id+'/student', body, {headers: headers}) to get something like http://localhost:9000/routes/grades/v1/course/'10/student.  But now when i submit, i get an error saying http://localhost:9000/routes/grades/v1/course/'undefined/student

Comment: well, it works fine on my postman

Comment: That crucial information should be in the question. So, `user.id` is undefined. The user is passed by the component: `addGrades(this.model)`. So, inside `this.model`, the field `id` is undefined. Why do you think it **should** be defined? Where is the code that reads the id from the route, and sets it into `this.model.id`?

Comment: Thanks i worked it out